# HighCharts Arearange Chart not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsfiddle

Can anyone tell me why my HighCharts Script isn't rendering a chart?

I mean its the most possible basic configuration for an arearange chart, but nothing happens...

```
$(function () {

var ranges = [
    [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
    [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
    [1246579200000, 15.5, 29.6],
    [1246665600000, 16.7, 30.7],
    [1246752000000, 16.5, 25.0],
    [1246838400000, 17.8, 25.7]
];

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'arearange'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'test',
        data: ranges
    }]

});
});
```

I tried to execute this in jsfiddle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind...

The following script reference was missing in the head:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```